# Getting ".ajax is not a function" for a single input submit by jQuert + Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a span to submit an input to server, but at firebug console I'm getting that error "TypeError: $(...).siblings(...).children(...).ajax is not a function"...

I don't know what's wrong in the code...

Here is my code

the HTML

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>Subject</p>
                <span></span>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="subject1">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>Degree</p>
                <span></span>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="degree1">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>Information</p>
                <span></span>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="information1">
                </div>

            </td>
            <td>
                <p>Tips</p>
                <span></span>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="tips1">
                </div>

            </td>
            <td>
                <p>Class</p>
                <span></span>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="class1">
                </div>

            </td>
            <td>
                <p>Final</p>
                <span></span>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="final1">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

The jQuery

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function (){
    var editIcons = $('td').children('span')
    var editDivs = $('td').children('div')
    var spanClick = 0;

    editIcons.hide();
    editDivs.hide();

    $('table').on ('mouseenter mouseleave','td',function (){
            $(this)
                .children('span')
                    .fadeToggle(200);
    });
    $('table').on ('click','span',function (){
            if (spanClick == 0){
                $(this)
                    .css('background-image','url(doneIcon-small.png)')
                    .siblings('div')
                        .fadeToggle(200);
                spanClick = 1;
                return;
            };
            if (spanClick == 1){
                $(this)
                    .css('background-image','url(editIcon-small.png)')
                    .siblings('div')
                        .fadeToggle(200);

                spanClick = 0;

                $(this)
                    .siblings('div')
                        .children('input')
                            .ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "some.php",
                                data: { name: $(this).attr("name"), value: $(this).val() },
                                success: function(data) {
                                        console.log(data);
                                        }
                                });
            };
    });
})();
</script>
```

The CSS

```
form, table {width:1024px; margin:0px auto; table-layout:fixed;}
    input[type="submit"] {float:right !important; padding:5px 25px; font-size:18px; margin-top:30px;}
    td {position:relative; display:block; width:168px; float:left; text-align:center;}
        td span {position:absolute; top:0px; right:0px; height:23px; width:20px; background-image:url(editIcon-small.png); cursor:pointer; z-index:1;}
        td div {position:absolute; top:0px; height:100%; width:100%; background-color:#FFF;}
            div input {display:block; padding:5px; border:solid 2px #006; border-radius:10px 0px; margin:15px 2px;}
```

Comment: ajax is a static function...

Comment: `ajax` is a function of the `jQuery` object: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/, http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/. If you read the documentation/tutorial you will know how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ajax is not a plugin method... it is a static function of the jQuery object. So try

```
var $input = $(this)
    .siblings('div')
    .children('input');

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: {
        name: $input.attr("name"),
        value: $input.val()
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (jqXhr, status, error) {
        alert(status + ':' + error + ':' + jqXhr.responseText)
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this method but I get nothing at the console, why is that?

Comment: the ajax request may not be successful... is there any error message in the console... also check the network tab to see whether the ajax request is sent and what is the response

Answer (score 1):

As error says everything. The **$.ajax()** method is not defined for input type. And **$.ajax()** can not be called with reference to any html element, it can be calle only with reference to **Jquery ($)** as it is a **static** method.

```
    $.ajax({                      //OR JQuery.ajax({
        url: "test.html",
        context: document.body
    }).done(function() {
        $( this ).addClass( "done" );
    });
```

The **$.ajax()** function underlies all Ajax requests sent by jQuery. It is often unnecessary to directly call this function, as several higher-level alternatives like **$.get()** and **.load()** are available and are easier to use. If less common options are required, though, **$.ajax()** can be used more flexibly.

More details: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

If you are trying to load your ajax response to any html element then you can use **.load()** as follows.

```
    $( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html" );
```

More details: http://api.jquery.com/load/